# Simplify this regex to reduce its complexity

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube, sonarlint

SonarLint is currently yelling at me for the complexity of some regex I am using for tax ID numbers. I need to reduce the complexity from 21 to 20 and I simply cannot think of a way to do that. All of the solutions I've tried have only made it more complex...

The regex in question:

```
^\d{9}$|^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|^\d{2}-\d{7}$|^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$
```

It needs to match tax ID numbers in these specific formats, and nothing else:

555555555

555-55-5555

55-5555555

555-555-555

Comment: What flavor of regex?

Comment: When you say "in all formats" do you mean all the *specific* formats you listed, and no others?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am using Java, so whatever the syntax/flavor for that is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, all of the specific formats I have listed.

Comment: `^(-?\d){9}$` should do it or if you allow `--` too, then change the question mark into an asteriks `*`

Comment: @Theo, that will accept alot more formats than those presented.  It is my understanding of the question and comments that *only* the four formats specified should be matched by the wanted regex.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep, I was going for _"all formats"_

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise. I am looking for the regex to match only the 4 specified formats. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: What about: `^\d\d(?:-?\d{7}|\d-\d\d(?:-\d|\d-)\d{3})$` ?

Comment: Do you really want a solution that satisfies SonarLint, even if it makes it harder for a human to understand (like @trincot's comment -- no offense)?

Comment: It might be enough to replace both `\d{2}` with `\d\d`.

Comment: @trincot replacing \d{2} with \d\d worked. Not the prettiest or most elegant solution, but it made Sonar happy and that's all that matters to the people up top. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Sonar's discussion of regex complexity](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5843) suggests considering replacing the regex with regular code (which I infer might involve simpler regexes in some cases).  Here, it looks like it would be straightforward to do that by testing each alternative via a separate regex instead of cramming them all into one, so do consider that.

The same discussion describes how Sonar computes regex complexity:

> Each of the following operators increases the complexity by an amount
> equal to the current nesting level and also increases the current
> nesting level by one for its arguments:
>
> - `|` - when multiple | operators are used together, the subsequent ones only increase the complexity by 1
> - `&&` (inside character classes) - when multiple `&&` operators are used together, the subsequent ones only increase the complexity by
>   1
> - Quantifiers (`*`, `+`, `?`, `{n,m}`, `{n,}` or `{n}`)
> - Non-capturing groups that set flags (such as `(?i:some_pattern)` or `(?i)some_pattern`)
> - Lookahead and lookbehind assertions
>
> Additionally, each use of the following features increase the
> complexity by 1 regardless of nesting:
>
> - character classes
> - back references

That produces 21 through 9 quantifiers, each at nesting level 2, plus three `|` operators, all at nesting level 1: 2 * 9 + 3 == 21.

I doubt that a less complex regex exists for this job, especially one that achieves the spirit of this Sonar rule: to make regex usages easy to read and maintain.  However, you should still be able to get Sonar to accept it without complaint by leveraging this:

> If a regular expression is split among multiple variables, the
> complexity is calculated for each variable individually, not for the
> whole regular expression. If a regular expression is split over
> multiple lines, each line is treated individually if it is accompanied
> by a comment (either a Java comment or a comment within the regular
> expression), otherwise the regular expression is analyzed as a whole.

I think that means that something along these lines would be acceptable to Sonar:

```java
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
            // xxxxxxxxx
            "^\d{9}$"
            // xxx-xx-xxxx
            + "|^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"
            // xx-xxxxxxx
            + "|^\d{2}-\d{7}$"
            // xxx-xxx-xxx
            + "|^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$"
            );
```

The docs lead me to believe that there would be other viable variations along similar lines of expressing the regex pieces separately.